# Finding the number of rows of each user in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have databases of users and each has tables. I want to loop through each user and find the number of rows of a particular table common to each. So i connect to the first DB(usersDB) and pick the names of other DB's from a table(userinfo) row(user_name). I then connect to each DB using the names obtained in userinfo and try to find the number of rows they each have on a particular table(products) common to them. I tried this but shows the same number of rows for all of them. Any help??

```
<?php
  //db parameters
 $dbhost = "localhost";   
 $dbname = "usersDB";
$dbuser = "root";   
$dbpass = ""; 

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  


 //select main db
 $query  = "SELECT user_name FROM userinfo";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))
  {
$dbName =$row['user_name'];
  mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
  mysql_select_db("dbprefix_".$bName) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// do a query for each db
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `products`');        
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
   echo $dbName." has".$num_rows."products"."<br/>";
} 
  ?>
```

Comment: Have you broken it down to check the variables are what you think they should be? Also what number are you getting out, do you know if it is the first db row count 1 or 0?

Comment: @BenWells: Yes It counts 1. Anyway the problem was that i was not closing the connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may not be your issue but I noticed you arn't closing the connection to each database after you query from it. you should assign a variable to `mysql_select_db` and after you echo close the database like this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
   $dbName =$row['user_name'];
   $db = mysql_select_db("dbprefix_".$dbName, $conn) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error()); 
    if( $db ){
        // do a query for each db
        $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `products`');        
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        echo $dbName." has".$num_rows."products"."<br/>";

        mysql_close( $db );
    }
}
```

also notice I took the mysql_connect() line out of the while loop because you don't need to call this more than once. and I added the `$conn` variable for your mysql_connect() command, this way you can use $conn in your mysql_select_db() statement.  This tell the select_db statement which connection to look in for this database (just alittle more secure).

Comment: Thanks. It was due to synthax errors and not closing the DB mysql_Close (). It worked. I want to escape breaking execution when there's no database. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @karto - I edited my post to reflect what you want to do.  Basically by checking if $db = true we are asking if $db is a valid database connection otherwise it will be false and nothing will happen.

Comment: I also edited my answer to include the syntax error you and the other answerers are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is in following line

```
mysql_select_db("dbprefix_".$bName) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

I think this line will be

```
mysql_select_db("dbprefix_".$dbName) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks for the corrections. It was a combination of mysql_select_db("dbprefix_".$bName) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error()); and mySQL Close ();

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is a typo here:

```
 mysql_select_db("dbprefix_".$bName) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

Did you mean "dbprefix_".$dbName instead of $bName?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Solved now. it was non-closure of my connections.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

every time, just call mysql_select_db for each database and PHP will reuse the connection

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy paste from php manual may be it helps you

If you use implode() with the return value by mysql_fetch_array,

if you use MYSQL_BOTH on parameter 2, the result is not really what you're expecting.

For example : 
my sql database contains "Amine, Sarah, Mohamed";

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($resource,MYSQL_BOTH); 
or $array = mysql_fetch_array($resource); 
echo implode(" - ", $array);
```

the result is : Amine-Amine-Sarah-Sarah-Mohamed-Mohamed 
and we expect just : Amine-Sarah-Mohamed

You must use MYSQL_NUM or MYSQL_ASSOC on parameter 2 to resolve the problem.

Comment: @G molvi: thanks . its worked. MYSQL_ASSOC was'nt the problem, but i had some synthax errors and did not close my connections.

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather inefficient to start up a new connection, using the same user/password for every user you've got. MySQL is perfectly capable of querying across different databases from the same connection:

```
mysql_connect(...);
$sql = "SELECT user_name FROM userinfo";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) {

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $username = $row['user_name'];
   $sql2 = "SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM dbprefix_{$username}.products";
   $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or (die(mysql_error());
   echo "$username has {$result2['cnt']} products";
}
```

In short, doing

```
SELECT somedb.sometable.somefield
```

is the same as doing

```
mysql_select_db('somedb');
SELECT sometable.somefield;
```